# Expression Engine 3 pagination with page_uri

Tags: pagination, ee3

I have looked for a while for a solution to this, but have been unsuccessful so far. Not sure if it's me, or if there's a problem with the pagination functionality.

**What I'm trying to do**

When on a page within a certain channel, I want to have 'prev' and 'next' buttons to click through to the next article in the channel. These links must use the page_uri set for each page.

**What I've tried**

I have a channel full of pages. In the template, I have added:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="project" dynamic="no" orderby="date" sort="desc" limit="1" paginate="bottom"}
    <div class="container-fluid project-section pagination-bar">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              {paginate}
              {pagination_links}
              <ul>
                {previous_page}
                <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-previous">Previous Page</a></li>
                {/previous_page}

                {next_page}
                <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-next">Next Page</a></li>
                {/next_page}
              </ul>
              {/pagination_links}
              {/paginate}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {/exp:channel:entries}
```

This is adding the links to the bottom of the page, but when clicking on them the URLs are just loading the same URL you're currently on, then adding /P1 to the end.

I need it to use the page_uri added in the CMS so that it clicks through properly and doesn't affect SEO on the site.

Any help appreciated on this one, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the documentation for previous/next linking https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channel/entry_linking.html